# How to avoid SQLCODE=-968, SQLSTATE=57011 "The file system is full" error with merge statement

Tags: db2, db2-luw, db2-10.5

When doing the following merge (`tempchoices` is a temporary table created with `DECLARE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE tempchoices LIKE CHOICES NOT LOGGED IN importtemp ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS`) all my diskspace gets used and I receive the "The file system is full" error.

```
MERGE into CHOICES ar  
USING (SELECT * from session.tempchoices ) ac  
ON ar.CHOICE_NAME = ac.CHOICE_NAME AND ar.CHOICE_LIST_NAME = 
'account' AND ar.LOCALE = 'de_CH'
WHEN MATCHED and ar.DISPLAY_NAME != ac.DISPLAY_NAME THEN 
UPDATE SET DISPLAY_NAME = ac.DISPLAY_NAME, DEPENDENT_VALUE = 
ac.DEPENDENT_VALUE 
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN 
INSERT (CHOICE_LIST_NAME, CHOICE_NAME, DISPLAY_NAME, VALUE, LOCALE, 
SORT_ORDER, DEPENDENT_VALUE) 
VALUES (ac.CHOICE_LIST_NAME, ac.CHOICE_NAME, ac.DISPLAY_NAME, ac.VALUE, 
ac.LOCALE, ac.SORT_ORDER, ac.DEPENDENT_VALUE)
```

How can I avoid this error?

Resizing the disk is not an option.

What I have tried is setting the `DB2_OPT_MAX_TEMP_SIZE` option but with no observable result.

Both tables contain about 600'000 entries.

DB2 Version is 10.5 and I observe this both on Linux and Windows servers.

Comment: Start with the detailed access plan from db2exfmt tool.  What indexes exist on table CHOICES ?  Did you also index tempchoices on CHOICE_NAME  before running the merge?  What is the size of the bufferpool(s) allocated to the tablespace(s) containing CHOICES and tempchoices?  Is STMM enabled?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the merge statement needs to use some amount of temp table size, you should increase the file system size where the related user temporary tablespace resides.

To check the path of user temporary tablespace,

- check `db2diag` message that may indicate which file system is related.
- And also, `db2pd -db <dbname> -tablespace`

You may add new user temp tablespace on new path that has enough space for the same page size of related tables.

Comment: That would be system temporary tablespace(s), not user. And the page size required is not related to the "related tables", but to the width of the row set being sorted.